# Scope variable returns error with length

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

```
var test = $scope.newgoal.gTitle;

console.log(test.length);
```

Even doing a code test as short as this one... it returns the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

I tried searching various solutions with no luck. you can see the partial controller codes here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Yp9z4aeVV9JOiCZH12Na?p=info

Please help. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the error says the property, length, can't be read. Look even closer and you'll see that `'length' of undefined` can't be read -  **"of undefined"**.

The problem isn't with `length`, it's with `test`. This error message is saying that `test` is undefined.

Since `test` simple points to `$scope.newgoal.gTitle`, this means that `$scope.newgoal.gTitle` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried console.log(test) to see what the actual variable is?
Perhaps try test['length'] if it's an object within test.

Also looking at the Plnkr it doesn't look like it's being initialized, so your variable test might be undefined.

Comment: uhm... it says `var test`... :)

Comment: yes but your $scope.newgoal.gTitle doesn't look like it's actually anything. Did you try console logging test? What did it give you?

Answer (score 0):

This means that your $scope.newgoal.gTitle is undefined. Try to log it with console.log($scope.newgoal.gTitle) for example.

Comment: it only goes through if I type into the textbox where $scope.newgoal.gTitle is responsible... is there anyway to check if the textbox is empty? :)

Comment: if($scope.textBoxModel) is okay to test the content of the box

Comment: but how do I set it specific to newgoal.gTitle?

Comment: Put a ng-model on a textfield like ng-model="newgoal.gTitle"